# Could I use apps developed with android N platform on previous versions of android OS

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

Seems google introduce quite a lot of interesting features in android N platform, for example Java 8 partial support. I want to use it for my first android application. However I have a question - if my app will be implemented using Android N tools using Java 8 features, but with settings minimal sdk = `4.1` will my application work on Android 4, 5, 6?

Comment: "I want to use it for my first android application" -- that is not a good idea, IMHO. Wait until Android N ships in final form (presumably "Android 7.0") in a few months.

Comment: I'm new to android and it's mostly for learning. But my personal phone running Android 5 so I need to know - will my app will work on it or no.

Comment: Not right now. Apps compiled against the N Developer Preview will only run on N Developer Preview devices, unless you take some fairly nasty and complicated steps to try to work around that restriction. That is one of the reasons why I suggest that you wait on using Android N until it ships in final form.

Comment: thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your app will work on previous versions of Android if you use the Support Libraries. These are updated with new versions of Android to provide backwards compatibility to new features. This is a common practice.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

For Java 8, it sounds like you will need to be selective in what you use.

From the documentation: https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs
Android does not currently support all Java 8 language features. However, the following features are now available when developing apps targeting the Android N Preview:

Default and static interface methods

Lambda expressions (also available on API level 23 and lower)

Repeatable annotations

Method References (also available on API level 23 and lower)

Note: To test lambda expressions and method references on earlier versions of Android, go to your build.gradle file, and set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 23 or lower. You will still need to enable the Jack toolchain to use these Java 8 features.

Comment: The OP's app will not work on previous versions of Android until Android N ships in final form, unless the OP takes significant steps. Once you specify that you are compiling and targeting `'N'`, your app's `minSdkVersion` is raised to `'N'` and your app will only run on N Developer Preview devices. Beyond that, I am personally a bit hazy as to what portions of the Java 8 support will be backwards compatible or not, and little of that will necessarily be covered by the Android Support libraries.

Comment: in this artice mentioned that support libraries mostly used to fix lacking of API. But in my case it wil be next language version. Are you sure it's fit for that case?

Comment: sounds like it's going to be a mixed bag for Java 8. If you want to make sure your app is backwards compatible you are going to have to be selective in what your use. Looks like Lambdas and Method References are already useable on previous versions but other features are not. Here is a better reference for what you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer I gave, please accept it. Thank you and good luck!